# Should I learn to play Chords using left hand or Right hand on Piano?

Tags: piano

I am a learner of Piano. I have seen many tutorials in youtube, in which the chords are played using left hand and melody using right hand. I come from India. I have heard so many songs that are played using this pattern on a keyboad and it sounds very nice to my ears. I recently enrolled in a piano course in Udemy, but the tutor uses right hand for chords. So, I am really confused at this stage. Is it wrong to play chords using left hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all. There is no "wrong" way to play the piano, and different compositions will require different feats of dexterity. Most of the popular music I encounter is "left-hand rhythm dominant," where the left hand creates the chord structure in the lower octaves and the right hand fills the upper octaves with melody. However, exceptions are many throughout the history of music. Pieces which require that the left and right hand both play chords at varying times no doubt exist.

Practice both. When you reach the limits of self-taught dexterity, seek out a teacher who can lay hands on yours. I don't know why this helps but it does. Listen to as much piano music as you can find to train your ear, and play along with it to train your hands.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am 40 and keen to learn piano and I am ready to put a lot of hard work :).Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I am glad to have helped you, sir. I do not believe that the human mind experiences age-related difficulties in learning, and believe that these pursuits help our minds stay keen as we age. I saw a recent documentary where a man had lost his memories but was still fluent in the piano and in speech. All my best to you as you hone your practice.

Comment: "seek out a teacher who can lay hands on yours" -- what?

Comment: @DavidBowling A teacher who can physically adjust the position of your hands to demonstrate the correct posture.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you should be learning both ways i.e to learn to play the chords with your left hand and notes with the right hand, vice-versa and sometimes also both hands at once, depending upon the song/music requirement.

But usually when starting to play the piano, its good if you learn to play the chord with your left hand and the melody with your right hand.

Comment: Can you point me to any online tutorial that teaches chords using left hand. Almost every tutorial on Udemy, teaches right hand chord playing. I am not comfortable with right hand chords because I started practicing it using left hand.

Comment: I have been learning from this course: https://www.learnandmaster.com/piano/, and now almost about to finish it. This course has given me a good amount of idea, not just on left/right hand chord playing but also on various piano playing styles like arpeggio, compound arpeggio, blues etc...

If you aren't able to buy the course, you can go for the torrent way here: https://tinyurl.com/y8h6g7rz

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to play chords in both the right and left hand. However, full chords in the left hand should not be played below the C below middle C because they will sound muddy. Piano playing requires both hands to sometimes play the melody and sometimes the harmony. Independence between the hands and fingers is necessary, whether it be in the form of chords or in the form of one hand playing staccato and the other legato. It's just something you have to get used to.